# Securing form data with base64?

Tags: php, forms, email, encryption, base64

In my form, I have to include a selection of details for sending, in a hiddenFields div.

For the 'sender_name', 'sender_email' and 'subject', I want to ensure this data is secure to help stop anyway taking the details.

I am currently using 'base64' to encode these, then decode them before processing and sending the form data by email.

```
<form action="" class="" etc>

    <div class="hiddenFields">
        <input name="sender_name" value="Q2hyaXN0b3BoZXIgWVz" type="hidden">
        <input name="sender_email" value="aW5mb0BjJpc2Rhdmllc3dlYmRlc2lnbi50=" type="hidden">
        <input name="subject" value="TmV3IENvbnRgRW5xdWlyeQ==" type="hidden">
        <input name="required" value="name|email|message" type="hidden">
        <input name="return" value="contact-sent" type="hidden">
        <input name="ACT" value="66" type="hidden">
        <input name="RET" value="index.php/contact" type="hidden">
        <input name="site_id" value="1" type="hidden">
        <input name="csrf_token" value="7420f717d3135576cd605be5ccc6b92dcc" type="hidden">
    </div>

    FIELD GO HERE

</form>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions to any reason this is a bad idea? or if there is a better alternative to encrypt the data perhaps?

Comment: It's a bad idea since it's not an encryption in any way, it's an encoding. If you want to protect traffic in-flight - use https.

Comment: Your setting the values from the server so why put them in the form? Anything not required by js or such just leave on the server.

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone have any suggestions to any reason this is a bad idea?

**Base64 is encoding, not encryption.** The information is not hidden, it's just represented in another form. Basicaly anyone can take the value and decode to plain bytes (string, number, whatever it is).

Lets decide what and where you want to hide.

If you want to hide the data from any 3rd party eavesdropper (man-in-the-middle), just use basic TLS (https). It will take care of confidentiality and integrity for you.

If you want to hide data from the (web) client sending the form, then the best option would be keeping the information on the server if possible.

If you must keep your server stateless (not to store anything on the server-side), you should properly encrypt the data (it means having some secret key, salt, authentication tag, ..).

When you don't know where to start, maybe using some [encrypted JWT token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516) as the posted value would be safe bet.

Comment: Note: "sending the form data by **email**" so HTTPS is not an option.

Comment: @zaph it does not matter how OP is using the data after it was received on the server, their current concern is securing a transfer between a client and a server.